# Simple calculation of sector coefficients using PHP

Tags: beginner, php, object-oriented, json, finance

#### Function

This class extends the key class, called [`EQ`](https://github.com/emarcier/usco/tree/cb5bf7ebb05af82210510c9ae28aed2a1beee612/master/cron/equity), and does basic calculation based on minutely data. It then calculates weight coefficients (e.g., [0, 1]) for sectors of equity exchange markets using data from market movers (e.g., `AAPL`, `GOOG`, `AMZN`, `NVDA`, `FB`).

It works, I'm not so sure about its OOP.

Would you be so kind and review it?

#### SectorCalculations

```
class SectorCalculations extends EQ implements ConfigConstants
{

    /**
     *
     * @var an array of sector movers
     */
    static $sector_movers;

    /**
     *
     * @var a string of current time
     */
    static $current_time;

    /**
     *
     * @var a string of current time
     */
    static $database_file_permission = 0755;

    public static function calculateSectorCoeffs()
    {
        $base_url_api = self::BASE_URL_API . self::TARGET_QUERY_API;

        $index_data = array("Overall" => array("sector_weight" => 1, "sector_coefficient" => 1, "sector_value" => 0));
        foreach (self::getSectorMovers() as $sector_mover) {
            $sector_url_api = $base_url_api . implode("%2C", array_keys($sector_mover["selected_tickers"])) . "&types=quote&range=1m";
            $raw_sector_json = file_get_contents($sector_url_api);

            if (ConfigConstants::WRITING_INDICES_SECTOR_DATA_ON_DATABASE == true) {
                self::writeIndicesOnDatabase($sector_mover["directory"], $raw_sector_json);
            }

            $raw_sector_array = json_decode($raw_sector_json, true);

            // Calculate the real-time index
            $index_value = 0;
            foreach ($raw_sector_array as $ticker => $ticker_stats) {
                if (isset($sector_mover["selected_tickers"][$ticker], $ticker_stats["quote"], $ticker_stats["quote"]["extendedChangePercent"], $ticker_stats["quote"]["changePercent"], $ticker_stats["quote"]["ytdChange"])) {

                    $change_amount = ($ticker_stats["quote"]["extendedChangePercent"] + $ticker_stats["quote"]["changePercent"] + $ticker_stats["quote"]["ytdChange"]) / 200;
                    $index_value += $sector_mover["sector_weight"] * $sector_mover["selected_tickers"][$ticker] * $change_amount;
                }
            }

            $index_data[$sector_mover["sector"]] = array("sector_weight" => $sector_mover["sector_weight"], "sector_coefficient" => $sector_mover["sector_coefficient"], "sector_value" => $index_value);
            $index_data["Overall"]["sector_value"] += $index_data[$sector_mover["sector"]]["sector_value"];
        }

        // Calculate the index factor for better visibility between -1 and +1
        $front_index_data = array();
        foreach ($index_data as $sector_name => $sector_index_data) {

            $index_sign = abs($sector_index_data["sector_value"]);
            $index_factor = 1;
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                $index_factor = pow(10, $i);
                if (($index_factor * $index_sign) > 1) {
                    $index_factor = pow(10, $i - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            $front_index_data[$sector_name] = $sector_index_data["sector_weight"] * $sector_index_data["sector_coefficient"] * $sector_index_data["sector_value"] * $index_factor;
        }

        $index_sector_file = self::writeFinalJSONforSectorCoeffsOnDatabase();

        self::copyFinalSectorCoeffsToFrontDirectory();

        if (EQ::isLocalServer()) {echo "YAAAY! " . __METHOD__ . " updated sector coefficients successfully !\n";}

        return $front_index_data;
    }

    public static function copyFinalSectorCoeffsToFrontDirectory()
    {
        $sector_dir = __DIR__ . self::LIVE_DATA_DIR_APP;
        if (!is_dir($sector_dir)) {mkdir($sector_dir, self::getDatabaseFilePermission(), true);} // if data directory did not exist

        // if s-1 file did not exist
        if (!file_exists($sector_dir . self::DIR_FRONT_SECTOR_COEF_FILENAME)) {
            $handle = fopen($sector_dir . self::DIR_FRONT_SECTOR_COEF_FILENAME, "wb");
            fwrite($handle, "d");
            fclose($handle);
        }

        $sector_coef_file = $sector_dir . self::DIR_FRONT_SECTOR_COEF_FILENAME;
        copy($index_sector_file, $sector_coef_file);
    }

    public static function writeFinalJSONforSectorCoeffsOnDatabase()
    {
        // Write the index file
        $index_sector_dir = __DIR__ . self::INDEX_SECTOR_DIR_PREFIX_APP;

        if (!is_dir($index_sector_dir)) {mkdir($index_sector_dir, self::getDatabaseFilePermission(), true);}

        $index_sector_file = $index_sector_dir . self::getCurrentTime() . ConfigConstants::EXTENSION_JSON;

        $index_sector_json = json_encode($front_index_data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        $file_handle = fopen($index_sector_file, "a+");
        fwrite($file_handle, $index_sector_json);
        fclose($file_handle);

        return $index_sector_file;
    }

    public static function writeIndicesOnDatabase($sector_mover_database, $raw_sector_json)
    {

        // Write the raw file in the back directories

        $rawSectorDir = __DIR__ . self::EACH_SECTOR_DIR_PREFIX_APP . $sector_mover_database;

        // if back directory not exist
        if (!is_dir($rawSectorDir)) {mkdir($rawSectorDir, self::getDatabaseFilePermission(), true);}

        // create and open/write/close sector data to back directories
        $rawSectorFile = $rawSectorDir . ConfigConstants::SLASH . self::getCurrentTime() . ConfigConstants::EXTENSION_JSON;
        $file_handle = fopen($rawSectorFile, "a+");
        fwrite($file_handle, $raw_sector_json);
        fclose($file_handle);

    }

    /**
     * @return a part of class object
     */
    public static function getSectorMovers()
    {
        return ConfigConstants::SECTOR_MOVERS_COEFFS;
    }

    /**
     * @return a part of class object
     */
    public static function getCurrentTime()
    {
        return date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
    }

    /**
     * @return a part of class object
     */
    public static function getDatabaseFilePermission()
    {
        return ConfigConstants::DATABASE_FILE_PERMISSION;
    }

}
```

#### json_encode($index_data)

> {"Overall":{"sector_weight":1,"sector_coefficient":1,"sector_value":0.0009989048910975919},"IT":{"sector_weight":0.18,"sector_coefficient":4,"sector_value":0.0002908602069845678},"Telecommunication":{"sector_weight":0.12,"sector_coefficient":4,"sector_value":8.05578227057372e-5},"Finance":{"sector_weight":0.1,"sector_coefficient":6,"sector_value":9.958073135395748e-5},"Energy":{"sector_weight":0.1,"sector_coefficient":6,"sector_value":8.529905787700634e-5},"Industrials":{"sector_weight":0.08,"sector_coefficient":8,"sector_value":8.477913513820296e-5},"Materials
>   and
>   Chemicals":{"sector_weight":0.08,"sector_coefficient":8,"sector_value":3.149808669009844e-5},"Utilities":{"sector_weight":0.08,"sector_coefficient":8,"sector_value":5.1996127293426994e-5},"Consumer
>   Discretionary":{"sector_weight":0.08,"sector_coefficient":8,"sector_value":9.118133207158268e-5},"Consumer
>   Staples":{"sector_weight":0.06,"sector_coefficient":8,"sector_value":7.264485191327639e-5},"Defense":{"sector_weight":0.04,"sector_coefficient":10,"sector_value":4.648512175199498e-5},"Health":{"sector_weight":0.04,"sector_coefficient":10,"sector_value":1.474285957230441e-5},"Real
>   Estate":{"sector_weight":0.04,"sector_coefficient":10,"sector_value":4.927955774543618e-5}}

#### Final Sector Coefficients

Sector Coefficients could be between (0, 1):

> {"Overall":0.9989048910975918,"IT":0.2094193490288888,"Telecommunication":0.38667754898753853,"Finance":0.5974843881237449,"Energy":0.5117943472620381,"Industrials":0.542586464884499,"Materials
>   and
>   Chemicals":0.20158775481663005,"Utilities":0.33277521467793275,"Consumer
>   Discretionary":0.5835605252581292,"Consumer
>   Staples":0.3486952891837267,"Defense":0.18594048700797994,"Health":0.058971438289217644,"Real
>   Estate":0.19711823098174472}

#### $ticker_stats sample

Quote array can be viewed in [this link](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#quote):

```
{
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "companyName": "Apple Inc.",
  "primaryExchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
  "sector": "Technology",
  "calculationPrice": "tops",
  "open": 154,
  "openTime": 1506605400394,
  "close": 153.28,
  "closeTime": 1506605400394,
  "high": 154.80,
  "low": 153.25,
  "latestPrice": 158.73,
  "latestSource": "Previous close",
  "latestTime": "September 19, 2017",
  "latestUpdate": 1505779200000,
  "latestVolume": 20567140,
  "iexRealtimePrice": 158.71,
  "iexRealtimeSize": 100,
  "iexLastUpdated": 1505851198059,
  "delayedPrice": 158.71,
  "delayedPriceTime": 1505854782437,
  "extendedPrice": 159.21,
  "extendedChange": -1.68,
  "extendedChangePercent": -0.0125,
  "extendedPriceTime": 1527082200361,
  "previousClose": 158.73,
  "change": -1.67,
  "changePercent": -0.01158,
  "iexMarketPercent": 0.00948,
  "iexVolume": 82451,
  "avgTotalVolume": 29623234,
  "iexBidPrice": 153.01,
  "iexBidSize": 100,
  "iexAskPrice": 158.66,
  "iexAskSize": 100,
  "marketCap": 751627174400,
  "peRatio": 16.86,
  "week52High": 159.65,
  "week52Low": 93.63,
  "ytdChange": 0.3665,
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that ordinarily the code within questions should *not* be changed after reviews have arrived. Since in this instance it's on the only answerer's request we'll allow it, but please take a look at *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a great deal to refine with this snippet -- good work.

- `$ticker_stats["quote"],` can be safely omitted from the `isset()` call because the subsequent checks on its subarrays will do the necessary work.  Good work supplying multiple parameters to a single `isset()` call.
- I may be able to refine the following section, but would need realistic sample input to be sure.

  ```
  foreach ($raw_sector_array as $ticker => $ticker_stats) {
      if (isset($sector_mover["selected_tickers"][$ticker], $ticker_stats["quote"], $ticker_stats["quote"]["extendedChangePercent"], $ticker_stats["quote"]["changePercent"], $ticker_stats["quote"]["ytdChange"])) {

          $change_amount = ($ticker_stats["quote"]["extendedChangePercent"] + $ticker_stats["quote"]["changePercent"] + $ticker_stats["quote"]["ytdChange"]) / 200;
          $index_value += $sector_mover["sector_weight"] * $sector_mover["selected_tickers"][$ticker] * $change_amount;
      }
  }

  $index_data[$sector_mover["sector"]] = array("sector_weight" => $sector_mover["sector_weight"], "sector_coefficient" => $sector_mover["sector_coefficient"], "sector_value" => $index_value);
  $index_data["Overall"]["sector_value"] += $index_data[$sector_mover["sector"]]["sector_value"];
  ```
- Rather than performing iterated "guess & check" arithmetic operations to determine the `$index_factor`, I think a non-iterative string check should be more direct/efficient.  You might write an implementation of Barmar's solution: [PHP - Find the number of zeros in a decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19801446/2943403) or a regex based approach: (though I'll admit it is a little challenging to interpret at a glance)

  ```
  $float = abs($float);
  $factor = pow(10, preg_match_all('~(?:^0?\.|\G(?!^))0~', $float)))
  ```

  https://regex101.com/r/SmlRp5/3

  If the above doesn't work for all of your cases (like `$float = 0`) you can write a earlier condition to shortcut a precise `0` to not receive a factor - but I reckon that this is not an expected case.

  ### Hmm, on second thought, there's greater stability to be had from using pure arithmetic. String-based processes are vulnerable to challenges dealing with scientific notation.

  I have added [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968143/2943403) to the earlier mentioned StackOverflow page that Barmar answered.
- For consistency, write all `if` blocks over multiple lines.  The reduction in lines is not worth the reduction in readability.

---

Some late advice...

```
$index_data["Overall"]["sector_value"] += $index_data[$sector_mover["sector"]]["sector_value"];
```

Is easier to read as:

```
$index_data["Overall"]["sector_value"] += $index_value;
```

Comment: @Emma On second thought, the more I research my advice on finding the `$factor` using string techniques, the more I am worried about running into conflicts with scientific notation.  Do you have some sample floats that I can run some tests on?

Comment: May I see what associative elements are in a single `$ticker_stats`?  More specifically, which keys are in the `quote` subarray.